# What instructions are executed before main() function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, it is said that the `main` function is the entry point (i.e "...where the first instructions of a program are executed...", see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point)). However, the following code prints `2` before `1` :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("1")
}

var print_me = println("2")
```

Why?

Comment: Variables are initialized top down, then `main` is invoked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the JVM loads any required classes.  As part of this, it will run any static initialisers.

Although your code looks like it's not in a class, Kotlin/JVM compiles it to one; that will have a field for `print_me`.  (How it's done is an implementation detail; it may be a static field on the class, or on an instance referred to through a static field.)  In any case, that field will have an initialiser.

Now, the type of `print_me` is `Unit`.  That's because the `println()` function doesn't return a useful value.  (Its sole reason is its side-effect.)  But the JVM will still run the initialiser, which will happily print "2" before returning `Unit` which gets assigned to `print_me`.

Later, once the class has been initialised, the runtime will call your `main()` function.

Of course, a static initialiser may call anything you like, so it could potentially do all sorts of things before hitting your `main()` function.  But in practice that doesn't happen too much.